# не могу установить Rmagick

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

```
$sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev    

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите 
невозможного,или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные 
вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.

Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
  libmagickwand-dev : Зависит: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev но он не будет установлен
  E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: не помогло, тупо переустоновил линукс

Comment: Ну, тоже вариант.